# Why my circle appear only half in animation video using manim library?

Tags: python, manim

When I run my below code, the video that render by manim library can only show half instead of a full circle, I do everything as instruction said.

```
from manim import *


class CreateCircle(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        circle = Circle()  # create a circle
        circle.set_fill(PINK, opacity=0.5)  # set the color and transparency
        self.play(Create(circle))  # show the circle on screen
```

I just want to learn how to code by using manim library, also this is my first post in overflowstack, so sorry if I do something wrong.

Comment: The code looks fine to me. Can you show a screenshot of the rendered video?

Comment: Thank you for try to help me out but I figure it out already (sorry I'm not polite, english is not my first langauge), all I do is just install a new version of it, acutally install from cmd cause first time I install from pycharm.